# Getting Error while running cost sigmoid cost function

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have a training data, with 1000 rows. I am using Tensorflow for training this data. Also trying to divide this into mini-batches of size 32. While Training the data, i am getting the error as mentioned below

InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [1000] vs. [32]
     [[{{node logistic_loss_1/mul}}]]

On the contrary, if i don't divide my training data into minibatches, or use a single minibatch of size 1000, the code works fine.

I have defined weights as tf.Variables and running the tensorflow session. See the code below

```py
def sigmoid_cost(z,Y):

    print("Entered Cost")
    z = tf.squeeze(z)
    Y = tf.cast(Y_train,tf.float64)

    logits = tf.transpose(z)
    labels = (Y)

    print(logits.shape)
    print(labels.shape)

    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels,logits=logits))


def model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test, learning_rate = 0.0001,
          num_epochs = 1500, minibatch_size = 32, print_cost = True):

    hidden_layer = 4

    m,n = X_train.shape
    n_y = Y_train.shape[0]

    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float64,shape=(None,n), name="X")    
    Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float64,shape=(None),name="Y")     
    parameters = init_params(n)

    z4, parameters = fwd_model(X,parameters)
    cost = sigmoid_cost(z4,Y)
    num_minibatch = m/minibatch_size
    print("Getting Minibatches")
    num_minibatch = tf.cast(num_minibatch,tf.int32)
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate = learning_rate).minimize(cost)
    print("Gradient Defination Done")

    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        sess.run(init_op)
        for epoch in range(0,num_epochs):
            minibatches = []
            minibatches = minibatch(X_train,Y_train,minibatch_size)
            minibatch_cost = 0

            for i in range (0,len(minibatches)):
                (X_m,Y_m) = minibatches[i]
                Y_m = np.squeeze(Y_m)
                print("Minibatch %d X shape Y Shape ",i, X_m.shape,Y_m.shape)
                _ , minibatch_cost = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={X: X_m, Y: Y_m})
                print("Mini Batch Cost is ",minibatch_cost)
            epoch_cost = minibatch_cost/num_minibatch

            if print_cost == True and epoch % 100 == 0:
                print ("Cost after epoch %i: %f" % (epoch, epoch_cost))

    print(epoch_cost)
```

For some reason, while running the cost function the size of either X or Y batch is being taken as 32, 100 or vice-versa. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting above error because of `Y = tf.cast(Y_train, tf.float64)` line inside `sigmoid_cost` function. Here, `Y_train` has `1000` rows, but loss function is expecting `32`(which is your batch size).

It should be `Y = tf.cast(Y, tf.float64)`. Infact, there is no need to cast data type here as `Y` is already of type `tf.float64`. Check below line:

```
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float64,shape=(None),name="Y")
```

That's why, when you were using a single minibatch of size `1000`(full `Y_train` data), your code was working fine.